# Will method calls in a thread from an object defined outside of a thread run threaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Would this method be ran in a thread even though it was defined out of the thread or would it be ran parallel? Would there be any side effects to this other than a race condition?

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass()
ThreadStart childref = new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    a.mass = a.CalculateMass() // Lets say this takes a minute to calculate.
});

Thread childThread = new Thread(childref);
childThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run in a separate thread.

Variables are just locations in memory that are only restricted by the process, not the thread. So a separate thread within your application can access that same location in memory.

There will be no other side effects besides race conditions if you don't take care to make sure that only one thread accesses it at any one time.

Comment: "only one thread accesses it at any one time." Are you referring to the object or the method?

Comment: Your `a` variable. Really, multiple threads can read it at the same time, but if any thread *updates* it, that's when you have to make sure no other thread is reading it otherwise weird things can happen.